# Can anyone send me a little Rinkeby testnet Eth

Tags: ether, nft, dapp-development, rinkeby

Can anyone send me a little Rinkeby testnet Eth.
my address is 0x08533abDC7573a127B1349Ad1b801AF8BCA4e5F8.
Thanks, hahaha...

Comment: Sent you 0.05e, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a great faucet that currently still works. It gives you tokens for all major testnets. You just need to connect it to twitter, however it doesn't post or anything:

https://faucet.paradigm.xyz/